Junit meta annotations. How to provide parameters into inner annotation?
Sorry for bad english
I want to merge some Junit annotations into one, for ease of reading code
Just simple example:
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Tag("tag")
    @Test
    public @interface TestTag {
        String value();
    }

And use it in my tests like that: @TestTag("myTag")
How can i provide "myTag" to @Tag in my TestTag annotation? It is possible without Spring?
I'm tried:

@Tag(value = this.value())
define string variable in class and try to fill it somehow


Currently, this is not possible with JUnit. See also this closed issue about annotation attribute overrides.
